# flask-sqlalchemy's db.create_all() doesn't create tables

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create new tables in my postgresdb but `db.create_all()` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I have a `models` class where I define all the tables, then in the `__init__.py`, I import the `models.py` file.

I get no errors, and debugging shows that it enters the file indeed and reach the `db.create_all()` line but does nothing with it.

`models.py`

```py
from flask import current_app as app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f"postgresql://postgres:{os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER_PASSWORD')}@localhost/postgres"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Visitor(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'visitors'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(256))
    key = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True)
    expire_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    location = db.Column(db.String)   
    company = db.Column(db.String)
    reason_of_visit = db.Column(db.String)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0))

    VISITOR_CREATE  = 'Issue Visitor Card'
    VISITOR_RETURN = 'Return Visitor Card'



db.create_all()
```

`__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
with app.app_context():
    from .api import models
```

The tables were created normally when I used `SQLAlchemy` instead of `Flask-SQLAlchemy`.

I know there are multiple questions for this topic but I couldn't find anything similar to my issue.

Comment: "The tables were created normally when I used SQLAlchemy" - are you trying to modify an already-existing table?

Comment: no, there are already a couple more tables created using SQLAlchemy and now I added a couple more and changed the schema to Flask-SQLAlchemy

Comment: There are only two reasons why a table might not be created but no error raised: (1) A table with that name already exists in the database (2) `db.create_all()` is called before the model definition code has been executed.